# finding the longest substrings python

Tags: python

Hello i am new to python programming i have a task that requires me to find the longest substrings i have some written down that outputs the longest substring but i need it to output two of the longest substring

```
def sequences(nums):
   pos1=0
   pos2=1
   seq1=0
   seq2=1

        while pos2<len(nums):
    
            if nums[pos2] != nums[(pos2-1)]:
               if seq2 - seq1 < pos2 - pos1:
                    seq1, seq2 = pos1, pos2
               pos1=pos2
            pos2+=1
    
        if seq2 - seq1 < pos2 - pos1:
          seq1, seq2 = pos1, pos2
        return nums[seq1:seq2]
    
    
seq3=sequences
print(seq3('10111000'))`
```

eg:'10111000' right now all i get is 111 but i would also like it to output 000 aswell i have been trying to find away to do it but cannot seem to crack it i would really appreciate your help
thank you

Comment: Your description is unclear.  The longest substring of some string is the string itself.  But from your examples, it looks like you only want substrings consisting of a single character.  Is that correct?  If so, you need to *say so*.  Be clear.

Comment: give examples of your input and expected output

Comment: If you want to output all single-character substrings of the maximum length, you need to collect them in a list (or some other collection of items). You're currently just returning a slice of the input string.

Comment: no am trying to get it to output two charters that is eg 111 and 000 but I don't know to implement it in the code

Comment: input: aaabbbabaabb output: aaa expected output: aaa bbb i know what I have written down cannot output what I want it to but that is why I put the code here so I could get pointers because am new to python coding I have been trying think of what to add to get my expected output I haven't been successful

Comment: Do you expect the output to be the string `"aaa bbb"` or do you expect it to be two strings in a list: `["aaa", "bbb"]`?

Comment: two strings in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to propose another solution, using `groupby`:

```
def longest_substrings(input: str):

    substring_generator = ("".join(g) for _, g in groupby(input))
    sorted_substrings = sorted(substring_generator, key=lambda x: -len(x))
    result = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted_substrings, key=lambda x: len(x))][0]
    return result

print(longest_substrings("1100111100111101100100001101"))
```

Output: `['1111', '1111', '0000']`

Basically what I do here is the following:

First I group the input string. This means, that groups will be created for each consecutive similar item, like for example 111 or 00. -> `substring_generator`

This I sort in a descending way by the strings' lengths. -> `sorted_substrings`

This sorted list I again group by the lengths of the strings and then I take the first element from it. -> `result`.

The result should be exactly what you asked for and I think it is very readable and understandable what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is probably to use a regular expression to find repeating sequences of all the characters:

```py
import re

def longest_substrings(input: str):
    # get all unique characters in the input string
    chars = set(input)

    # initialise max_length to zero
    max_length = 0

    # empty list to store output
    output = []

    # loop over all characters in the string
    for c in chars:
        # find all substrings of any length
        # matching *only* that character
        substrings = re.findall(f"{c}+", input)

        # loop over all substrings
        for substring in substrings:
            # check the length of the substring
            length = len(substring)

            # if longer than the previous max_length,
            # we replace the output list with just this
            # substring
            if length > max_length:
                output = [substring, ]
                max_length = length
            # if length is equal, we add this substring
            # to the output
            elif length == max_length:
                output.append(substring)

            # implicitly: if the length is less, we do
            # nothing

    return output

print(longest_substrings("1100111100111101100100001101"))
# ['1111', '1111', '0000']
```

`f"{c}+"` is a regex pattern that turns into `0+` for `0` and `1+` for `1`. The `+` means `match one or more repeating occurrences of this character`.

Comment: hi am trying to get it to out put something else when it is less but it outputs null set how do I change that

Comment: Output what instead? Describe the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: i am trying to add the condition that say if it length of the sequence is less than 2 it prints not greater than 2 which I have done and its working so thank you